# Help understanding my book's example of finding the eigenvalue of a function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:E \rightarrow E$ be a linear application. Let $\alpha$ be an eigenvalue of f and

$$E_\alpha = \{ u \in E:f(u) = \alpha u\}$$

My book then goes on to prove that $E_\alpha$ is a subspace of $E$:

$$E_\alpha = \{ u \in E : f(u) = \alpha u\} \\
=\{u \in E : f(u)-\alpha u = 0_E\} \\
= \{ u \in E : (f-\alpha *id_E)(u)=0_E\} \\
= \ker(f-\alpha*id_E)$$

I don't understand the 3rd and the last steps. Firstly what is $id_E$ in this context? I know it's supposed to be the identity function of... E? f? But what does that mean?

Secondly how do you go from $f(u)-\alpha u$ to $(f-\alpha*id_E)(u) $?

Thirdly I know that the kernel of f is a subspace of E, but this is the kernel of $f-\alpha*id_E$. Why is it still valid? I figure it's because $f-\alpha*id_E$ is also defined $E \rightarrow E$. Is that correct?

Comment: $id_E$ is the identity map; $id_E:E\to E$ defined for $u\in E$ by $id_E(u)=u$

Comment: and the kernel of any linear transformation is a subspace

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So $id_E(u)*\alpha = u*\alpha$?

Comment: yes, $\alpha * id_E(u)=\alpha * u$

Answer (score 2):

I think just checking the definition of a subspace would be the easiest way to see it, but as always there are many ways to show the desired result.

Any mathematical structure consisting of a set $X$ and some operations like $+$ or so come equipped with at least one structure preserving map, namely the identity function $\mathsf{id}_X:X\rightarrow X$ which just sends every element $x$ to itself. Note that no matter how your operations like $+$ look like, $\mathsf{id}_X$ preserves it, e.g. satisfies $\mathsf{id}_X(a+b) = \mathsf{id}_X(a) + \mathsf{id}_X(b)$, since $a+b=a+b$.

Moreover, we can replace every occurrence of an element $a$ by $id(a)$, by definition.

Now recall that if $f$ is a morphism of vector spaces and $id$ is another morphism of vector spaces, we can define the pointwise sum of both morphisms, ie. writing $(f + id)(x) := f(x) + id(x)$. This will give us another morphism of vector spaces, which we call $f + id$. The last step is then just seeing that the set second last set is the kernel of this sum $f+id$ of morphisms...